# Pointing to another object's attributes and adding your own

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, name, tank_size=10, mpg=30):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_size = tank_size
        self.mpg = mpg
```

I put together a list of the cars I'm looking at:

```
cars = []
cars.append(Car("Toyota", 11, 29))
cars.append(Car("Ford", 15, 12))
cars.append(Car("Honda", 12, 25))
```

If I assign a name to my current favorite (a "pointer" into the list, if you will):

```
my_current_fav = cars[1]
```

I can easily access the attributes of my current favorite:

```
my_current_fav.name       # Returns "Ford"
my_current_fav.tank_size  # Returns 15
my_current_fav.mpg        # Returns 12
```

Here's where I start getting foggy. I would like to provide additional "computed" attributes only for my current favorite (let's assume these attributes are too "expensive" to store in the original list and are easier to just compute):

```
my_current_fav.range      # Would return tank_size * mpg = 180
                          # (if pointing to "Ford")
```

In my case, I just capitulated and added 'range' as an attribute of Car().  But what if storing 'range' in each Car() instance was expensive but calculating it was cheap?

I considered making 'my_current_fav' a sub-class of Car(), but I couldn't figure out a way to do that and still maintain my ability to simply "point" 'my_current_favorite' to an entry in the 'cars' list.

I also considered using decorators to compute and return 'range', but couldn't figure out a way to also provide access to the attributes 'name', 'mpg', etc.

Is there an elegant way to point to any item in the list 'cars', provide access to the attributes of the instance being pointed to as well as provide additional attributes not found in the class Car?

**Additional information:**
After reading many of your answers, I see there is background information I should have put into the original question.  Rather than comment on many answers individually, I'll put the additional info here.

This question is a simplification of a more complicated issue.  The original problem involves modifications to an existing library.  While making range a method call rather than an attribute is a good way to go, changing

```
some_var = my_current_favorite.range
```

to

```
some_var = my_current_favorite.range()
```

in many existing user scripts would be expensive.  Heck, *tracking down* those user scripts would be expensive.

Likewise, my current approach of computing range for every car isn't "expensive" in Python terms, but *is* expensive in run-time because the real-world analog requires slow calls to the (embedded) OS.  While Python itself isn't slow, those calls are, so I am seeking to minimize them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easiest to do for your example, without changing `Car`, and changing as little else as possible, with `__getattr__`:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, name, tank_size=10, mpg=30):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_size = tank_size
        self.mpg = mpg

class Favorite(object):
    def __init__(self, car):
        self.car = car
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.car, attr)
    @property
    def range(self):
        return self.mpg * self.tank_size

cars = []
cars.append(Car("Toyota", 11, 29))
cars.append(Car("Ford", 15, 12))
cars.append(Car("Honda", 12, 25))

my_current_fav = Favorite(cars[1])

print my_current_fav.range
```

Any attribute not found on an instance of `Favorite` will be looked up on the `Favorite` instances `car` attribute, which you set when you make the `Favorite`.

Your example of `range` isn't a particularly good one for something to add to `Favorite`, because it should just be a `property` of car, but I used it for simplicity.

**Edit**: Note that a benefit of this method is if you change your favorite car, and you've not stored anything car-specific on `Favorite`, you can change the existing favorite to a different car with:

```
my_current_fav.car = cars[0] # or Car('whatever')
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting use of a property because it gives the appearance of an attribute without actually storing the value in the object.

Comment: Everything up to `my_current_fav = cars[0] # or Car('whatever')
 is well done, but that line replaces `my_current_fav` with an instance of `Car`, it does not update the instance of `Favorite`.

Comment: Excellent!  After posting I started ruminating on an approach similar this, but yours is clearly superior.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the class (and it sounds like you do), just create a function inside the class instead.

```
def range(self):
    return self.tank_size * self.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your example, you could make `range` a read-only [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) of class `Car` that would be computed on demand. No need for extra classes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a method:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, name, tank_size=10, mpg=30):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_size = tank_size
        self.mpg = mpg

    def range(self):
        return self.tank_size * self.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `range()` should  be a method of the class. Methods are very cheap - the objects don't store them. The downside is it is computed each time you access the value of `range`.

```
class Car(object):
   def __init__(self, name, tank_size=10, mpg=30):
       [AS ABOVE]
   def range(self):
      return self.tank_size * self.mpg
```

If you prefer it to behave like a field, i.e. compute only once, you can store the value in the object during the `range` method:

```
  def range(self):
     if not hasattr(self,'_rangeval'):
         self._rangeval = self.tank_size * self.mpg
     return self._rangeval
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you can dynamically create fields in objects.

I don't understand why the default would be 180 when the default of the computed values is 300. If this strange behaviour is important, you will need to set another flag to see if the other parameters have been initialised to the default or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, so I'm going to cover a few different possible understandings of what you're thinking.

> In my case, I just capitulated and added 'range' as an attribute of Car(). But what if storing 'range' in each Car() instance was expensive but calculating it was cheap?

First off, worrying about things being "expensive" is usually not that Pythonic. If it really mattered, you would be using a lower-level language most of the time. But in general, if you want something to be calculated rather than stored, the natural way is to use a method. Add it to the Car class. It **does not cost** per-object, unless of course you explicitly replace the method on a per-object basis.

Here's how it works: when you make a call to `a_car.range()`, the `range` attribute is looked up in `a_car` first. If it's not found there, then (*skipping lots and lots of details here!*) the class of `a_car` is identified as `Car`, and the attribute is looked up there. You define `range` as a `Car` method, so it gets found there, and is determined to be something that's actually callable, so it gets called. As a special syntax rule, `a_car` gets passed as the first parameter to the method (all of which partly explains why you need to have an explicit parameter - named `self` by convention - for methods in Python, unlike many other languages with an implicit `this`).

> I considered making 'my_current_fav' a sub-class of Car(), but I couldn't figure out a way to do that and still maintain my ability to simply "point" 'my_current_favorite' to an entry in the 'cars' list.

You can definitely store a subclass of `Car` in the same list as a bunch of ordinary `Car`s. No problem there. Heck, you can store a `Banana` in the same list as a bunch of `Car`s if you like; Python is dynamically typed, and doesn't care. It will figure out what kind of object something is at the exact moment that it becomes relevant.

What you can't easily do is cause an existing `Car` to become a `MyFavouriteCar`. If you created a new `MyFavouriteCar` that `my_favourite_car` refers to (don't say "points at", please; object references are a higher-level abstraction, and unlike Java there is no "null pointer" in Python - `None` is an object), then you could replace an existing car in the list with it, but it's still a different object (even if it's somehow based on the original `Car` that it replaces). You can design in such a way that this doesn't matter; or you can resort to evil hackery (which I won't explain here); or you can (much better in your case) *just offer the functionality to all Cars, because it's really free to do so*.

From the Zen of Python: **Special cases aren't special enough**.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about `my_current_fav` being a 'pointer' -- I just want to make sure you realize that, in fact,

```
my_current_fav = cars[1]
```

binds a name to `cars[1]` -- in other words, `my_current_fav is cars[1] == True`.  There is no pointing going on.  If you really want a pointer-stlye you can do something like this:

```
class Favorite(object):
    def __init__(self, car_list, index):
        self.car_list = car_list
        self.index = index
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.car_list[self.index], attr)
    def __index__(self):
        return self.index
    @property
    def range(self):
        return self.mpg * self.tank_size

my_current_fav = Favorite(cars, 1)

print my_current_fav.name
print my_current_fav.range
print cars[my_current_fav]
```

Comment: But if you do `cars[1] = 1234`or `my_current_fav = 1234` then the `is` will be `False` -- so they're both "pointers to the same thing" (in non-Python terminology) but they're not the same thing. I think that's what he meant.